# How to determine which subform has focus

Tags: vba, indexing, focus

I have a Form that contains several subforms.  On one of the subforms, I need to run an update query if you click off to another subform (you finished with the controls, if anything changed it must update).  This part works great.  The trouble I am having is I don't want to bog everything down by running the update (its a loop of update queries) every time you click on any subform.

If you are on a very specific subform (PageIndex 2) then it should run the updates.  Below is the code I have to determine which tab/page/subform I am on.  PlanSpecs is the name of the Page.

The problem is that no matter what tab I am current on, if always says "I'm on that subform."  Any idea why that might be, or any suggestions as to what I can do instead?

```
If (Me.PlanSpecs.PageIndex = 2) Then
    MsgBox ("I'm on that subform")
Else
    MsgBox ("Different Subform, move along")
End If
```

Comment: Is this within a TabControl?  If so, and PlanSpecs is the control, it looks like you can do `if me.parent!PlanSpecs.value = 2 then` [from here](http://www.office-forums.com/threads/page-index-of-a-tab-control-from-a-subform.614483)

Comment: I have labels on the main form, when you click on the label it activates the associated subform.  When I tried the code you provided, it said "The expression you entered has an invalid reference to the Parent property"

Comment: That makes sense.  I was getting thrown off by that property, PageIndex.  I cannot find anyway to reference them by a numeric index, only by name, but please try out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can refer to them by that index, unless they're in a tab control, then you'd have the PageIndex property.

You can however do it like this,

```
If (Screen.ActiveControl.Parent.Name = "SubFormNameHere") Then
    MsgBox ("I'm on that subform")
Else
    MsgBox ("Different Subform, move along")
End If
```

But this code may need additional conditions, for instance if you add a tab control to that subform, then it'll return the name of the TabControl and not the parent(form).

For [additional reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787979/how-do-i-reference-the-current-form-in-an-expression-in-microsoft-access)