# AutofillNewRecord type mismatch in subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to fill a new record with data from the previous record.
I don't know vba but I found this article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210236

Since I want all the fields to be automatically written in, I've just c/p the code and put `=AutofillNewRecord([Forms]![Abc])` on the current event property of Abc. It works perfectly.

Now the problem is Abc is actually a subform for MainForm. So, if I open Abc directly it's all fine but when I open it through MainForm it says "type mismatch" and the function (?) doesn't work at all.

> The expression OnCurrent you entered as the event property setting
> produced the following error: Type mismatch.
>
> The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
>
> There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

I've searched on Google but I couldn't find a solution.
I'm attaching a bare-bones example hoping someone could help.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fpnhkpreb75rxw/AutofillTest.accdb?dl=0

Btw, since I'm using a non-english version of Access you might need to change =AutofillNewRecord([Maschere]![abc]) under on current event to =AutofillNewRecord([Forms]![abc]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use an event procedure instead of directly entering `=AutofillNewRecord([Forms]![Abc])` for the Form_Current() event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    AutoFillNewRecord Me
End Sub
```

I've tried with your database and it worked here, independently of whether the form is used as subform (also independent of which parent) or opened as main form.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, do you know the reason why it wasn't working before?

Comment: It was the reference to the form when it was used as a subform. `[Forms]![Abc]` references to the opened form named `Abc`. If the form is being used as a subform, this reference won't work out anymore, but one would need to write something like `[Forms]![MainForm]![Abc]`. `Me`, on the other hand, always references to the form containing the VBA code, so this works in all places, regardless of how the form is being used/named.

Comment: Actually, I also tried this, but for some reason it didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787979/how-do-i-reference-the-current-form-in-an-expression-in-microsoft-access Maybe someone else can shed light on this?