# How to use a variable for the criteria in a query to restrict the query to the active form?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have form named "frmBond-MuniDetailsAE". It has a combo box named "cboStep". The Row Source for cboSteps is an embedded query that retrieves records from a table named "tblBond-Steps", and it has as Criteria -
[Forms]![frmBond-MuniDetailsAE]![SYM]. This restricts the query to records in tblBond-Steps to only those that have a SYM field that matches that field in the form. This works fine. But I would like to be able to copy and reuse the form for other types of bonds, and I don't want to have to rewrite the embedded query in each copied form. So I wanted to use a variable in the query criteria that would reference the current form.
Following answers given in StackOverflow at [How do I reference the current form in an expression in Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787979/how-do-i-reference-the-current-form-in-an-expression-in-microsoft-access), I wrote a Public Function named "FormName()". Here is the function:

```
Public Function FormName() As String
 Dim frmCurrentForm As Form
 Set frmCurrentForm = Screen.ActiveForm
 FormName = "[Form]![" & frmCurrentForm.Name & "]" & "![SYM]"

End Function
```

Then in the embedded query for the combo box, I entered "FormName()" as the criteria. Here is the SQL for that query:

```
SELECT [tblBond-Steps].SYM, [StepDate] & " @ " & [Cpn] AS Steps, Format([tblBond-Steps]. 
[StepCpn],"0.0000%") AS Cpn, [tblBond-Steps].StepDate
FROM [tblBond-Steps]
WHERE ((([tblBond-Steps].SYM)=FormName()))
ORDER BY [tblBond-Steps].StepDate;
```

But when I open the form with the above query as the Row Source for cboSteps, I get VBA Run-time error '2475': "You entered an expression that requires a form to be the active window."

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me with this, Gustav, but I still got the same error #2475 after I changed my Public Function FormName() so as to return the value, not the expression. This error occurs as soon as I open the form, and it highlights the assignment line of code that reads "Set frmCurrentForm = Screen.ActiveForm".

Comment: Correction to previous comment: I don't know what I was doing yesterday when I was trying to use Gustav's instructions. But today, using the corrected code that he provided, the form opens without causing Run-time error #2475. Thank you very much, Gustav, for telling me how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must return the *value*, not the expression:

```vb
Public Function FormName() As String

    Dim frmCurrentForm As Form

    Set frmCurrentForm = Screen.ActiveForm
    FormName = frmCurrentForm![SYM].Value

End Function
```